# code javascript quick answer

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why doesn't it work? I am trying now for a long time and there seem to be no end to it. Need to make it simple as possible

```
var firstInput = document.luckForm.numberBox.value;
 var secondInput = document.luckForm.numberBox2.value;
 var thirdInput = document.luckForm.numberBox3.value;



for (firstInput = 0; firstInput <= 10; firstInput++) {
if (firstInput = luckyNumber) {
if (secondInput = luckyNumber2) {
if (thirdInput = luckyNumber3) {

{alert('Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1000!'); }}}}}
```

I was trying to change this code (see below) into a for loop code, very simple with no arrays. I am not sure how I can do this. It is supposed to be for a lottery, you can type in three numbers and if they are correct you would get the message that you win 1000 pounds.

```
if (firstInput == luckyNumber && secondInput == luckyNumber2 && thirdInput == luckyNumber3 || firstInput == luckyNumber && secondInput == luckyNumber3 && thirdInput == luckyNumber2 || firstInput == luckyNumber2 && secondInput == luckyNumber3 && thirdInput == luckyNumber || firstInput == luckyNumber2 && secondInput == luckyNumber && thirdInput == luckyNumber3 || firstInput == luckyNumber3 && secondInput == luckyNumber && thirdInput == luckyNumber2 || firstInput == luckyNumber3 && secondInput == luckyNumber2 && thirdInput == luckyNumber)
    {
        alert('Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct. You\'ve won £1000!');
```

Comment: While comparing in the IF Conditions, you should put double equals "=="

Comment: What doesn't work?? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: why do you want to make it a for loop?

Comment: It is a task I have been given to train JavaScript. I find it not very useful, but I think I should know how to do it even though it doesn't make so much sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are *assigning* instead of *comparing*.

```
firstInput = luckyNumber
```

Should be:

```
firstInput == luckyNumber
```

Or better yet:

```
parseInt(firstInput, 10) === luckyNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a FOR loop here.  The numbers are entered once and then they are checked against the lucky numbers.  There is no need to iterate through a loop and check the same numbers over and over again.

If you want to loop through the entire process of getting numbers then checking those numbers against the lucky numbers and repeating if they do not match, you should use a DO-WHILE loop.

DO - get the numbers and check them against the lucky numbers.

WHILE - the numbers do not equal the lucky numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that statement is just trying to ensure that order doesn't matter. So that if you put the first number in the second box and the second in the first box but still got the same three numbers as the lotto, you still win.

(ie 23,35,15 wins if the outcome was 15,23,35)